# Displaying a image captured using Camera inside an html image tag placed within a WebView - Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-webview, android-camera2

I'm looking for a way on to display the image captured using Camera2 API in Xamarin.Android inside an HTML  tag which is placed within a WebView.

Though it was possible to obtain the File URi where the image is located, setting it into the image tag which I have tried, isn't working. I also want to know whether this kind of thing can be done in Native Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the content of the image in base64, and than set it in the src of your img tag like this:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,VeryLongBase64EncodedImageData"/>
```